# WordPress TinyMCE Add Button To The Full Screen Mode Editor

Tags: php, tinymce

I've created a button (named 'quote') in WordPress post editor (TinyMCE) normal mode, and I've been successful in adding some functionality to that button. The question is how can I make this button also appear in the 'full screen mode editor' (also known as Distraction Free Writing Mode).

functions.php:-

```
add_action('init', 'add_button');  
function add_button() {  
   if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') &&  current_user_can('edit_pages') )  
   {  
     add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin');  
     add_filter('mce_buttons_3', 'register_button');  
   }  
}  
function register_button($buttons) {  
   array_push($buttons, "quote");  
   return $buttons;  
}  
function add_plugin($plugin_array) {  
   $plugin_array['quote'] = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/customcodes.js';  
   return $plugin_array;  
}
```

I've googled and found that I might have to add some sort of filter. WordPress filters out buttons in the Full Mode, so I've to add the button again to the $buttons array. I believe that I'm pretty close to it.

Comment: Better suited for wordpress.stackexchange. I flagged for moderator attention, you should see this question get moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this link](http://mattvarone.com/wordpress/adding-tinymce-buttons-to-wordpress-3-2-fullscreen-mode/) for your issue. It will help you.

This is the link you are looking for: [Enjoy!](http://sumtips.com/2013/01/remove-or-add-buttons-in-wordpress-distraction-free-writing.html)